# JSON decode, Parse JSON response and Undefined Index on integer value

Tags: php, arrays, json, laravel, amazon-product-api

It's so weird that I have been working on this for three days looking around the web to find a solution and making my own changes but still have no luck. I'm trying to retrieve amazon products into my website with Laravel and this great package from [JoeDawson/amazon-ecs](https://github.com/JoeDawson/amazon-ecs).
when I execute the command from the controller like this below:

```
$results = Amazon::search('tv')->json();
dd($results)
```

I can see all the data from Amazon like this:

```
array:2 [
  "OperationRequest" => array:4 [
    ...
  ]
  "Items" => array:5 [
    ...
    "Item" => array:10 [
      ...
      "ItemAttributes" => array:22 [
          "Binding" => "Electronics"
          "Brand" => "LG Electronics"
          "Color" => "Black"
          "EAN" => "8806087769050"
          "EANList" => array:1 [
            "EANListElement" => "8806087769050"
          ]
          "Feature" => array:4 [
            0 => "High dynamic contrast ratio (5M:1) - richer colors, deeper blacks and greater depth of image"
            1 => "Gaming and cinema modes - dedicated features to optimise viewing experiences"
            2 => "USB AutoRun - media content from USB stick runs automatically as soon as TV is switched on"
            3 => "Detachable base - easy way to wall mount your TV and enjoy a viewing experience while saving space"
          ]
          "ItemDimensions" => array:4 [
            "Height" => "226"
            "Length" => "1560"
            "Weight" => "948"
            "Width" => "2526"
          ]
          "Label" => "LG"
          "ListPrice" => array:3 [
            "Amount" => "19999"
            "CurrencyCode" => "GBP"
            "FormattedPrice" => "£199.99"
          ]
      ]
    ]
  ]
]
```

Or the entire result is here: http://pastebin.com/TGFgCbAz

In my view, I have access to all the values except the values inside `ListPrice`, which gives back "Undefined Index"

```
@foreach ($results['Items']['Item'] as $amazon)
 {{ $amazon['ItemAttributes']['Title'] }} //returns true with the value
 {{ $amazon['ItemAttributes']['ListPrice']['FormattedPrice'] }} //returns Undefined index: ListPrice
@endforeach
```

I tried the same thing on the controller side:

```
foreach ($amazon_results['Items']['Item'] as $amazon) {
        print_r($amazon['ItemAttributes']['ListPrice']['FormattedPrice']);
    }
```

This returns the values of FormattedPrice first then throws the same error.

> £199.99£34.99£194.50 Whoops, looks like something went wrong.
>
> 1/1 ErrorException in HomeController.php line 24: Undefined index:
>   ListPrice

Why am I not able to get this value?

Comment: You may want to include the actual data you get back, not an excerpt that's been processed by something or other. Maybe `var_dump($results)`?

Comment: A good way to find an object in array if you are lost is to use function var_dump() it could maybe help you. I hope so.

Comment: ["ListPrice"]=> array(3) { ["Amount"]=> string(5) "19999" ["CurrencyCode"]=> string(3) "GBP" ["FormattedPrice"]=> string(8) "£199.99" }

Comment: The json is too much that can't be added here but I will update the post with the json data just how it looks like, thanks

Comment: What code produce such output?

Comment: var_dump($amazon_results); but I exculded the other parts that I don't need, and there's no errors. thanks

Comment: @miken32 I have updated the question with the entire output of JSON. Thanks

Comment: When asked for output, don't use `dd()` as it makes a mess of things. Use `var_dump()` if you must. (Ideally you'd have access to proper JSON data but it looks like the library you're using doesn't provide this.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hate to be the bearer of bad news, but it's simply that there is no `ListPrice` array for all the items. The full dump you provided had ten items. Two of them (index 7 and index 9) did not contain the `ListPrice` array. I'd suggest checking to make sure it exists first:

```
@foreach ($results['Items']['Item'] as $amazon)
 {{ $amazon['ItemAttributes']['Title'] }}
 @if (array_key_exists('ListPrice', $amazon['ItemAttributes']))
  {{ $amazon['ItemAttributes']['ListPrice']['FormattedPrice'] }}
 @else
  No list price
 @endif
@endforeach
```

Comment: Thanks Bro for everything